# Finding dynamic checkbox in jquery , But using only a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created function myself for this -

```
function countchecked(){
var i=0;
$('tbody[role="alert"] input:checkbox.multi-select').each(function () {
   var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).attr("uid") : "0");
   if(sThisVal!="0")
   {
    i++;
   }
    });
   return i;
}
```

This function work fine for static checkbox, but as i add dynamic checkbox it cant find them.

Here is the code for where all checkbox are added dynamically. Here is tr where each checkbox comes-

```
<table class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">

    <!-- Table heading -->

    <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 133px;">Name</th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Email: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 225px;">Email</th><th class="center sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Registration Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 155px;">Registration Date</th><th class="center sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Last Login: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 154px;">Last Login</th><th class="center sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Active: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 59px;">Active</th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Tools : activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 75px;">Tools <a class="point" id="del" uid="'.$item['id'].'"><img src="/lifelist/images/del_icon.png"></a></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- // Table heading END -->

    <!-- Table body -->

    <!-- // Table body END -->

<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="row12 odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">test admin</td>
    <td class="mail ">gdfhfkhfflhh@fhfhfh.com</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 17:09:27</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 17:09:27</td>    
    <td class="center ">Yes</td>

    <td class=" "><a class="point" onclick="edit(12)">Edit</a> &nbsp; 
     &nbsp; <input class="multi-select checkbox" type="checkbox" uid="12">
    <i></i></td>
    </tr><tr class="row8 even">
    <td class=" sorting_1">test neeharika</td>
    <td class="mail ">jiouu@yahoo.com</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 12:31:06</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 12:31:06</td>    
    <td class="center ">Yes</td>

    <td class=" "><a class="point" onclick="edit(8)">Edit</a> &nbsp; 
     &nbsp; <input class="multi-select checkbox" type="checkbox" uid="8">
    <i></i></td>
    </tr><tr class="row11 odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">test neeharika</td>
    <td class="mail ">gdfhfhfflhh@fhfhfh.com</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 14:05:14</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-07-30 14:05:14</td>    
    <td class="center ">Yes</td>

    <td class=" "><a class="point" onclick="edit(11)">Edit</a> &nbsp; 
     &nbsp; <input class="multi-select checkbox" type="checkbox" uid="11">
    <i></i></td>
    </tr><tr class="row4 even">
    <td class=" sorting_1">Tom Cruise</td>
    <td class="mail ">rohit@mail.com</td>
    <td class="center ">0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
    <td class="center ">2013-09-05 13:08:32</td>    
    <td class="center ">Yes</td>

    <td class=" "><a class="point" onclick="edit(4)">Edit</a> &nbsp; 
     &nbsp; <input class="multi-select checkbox" type="checkbox" uid="4">
    <i></i></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Ok this is what all process is-

1. User check any check box.
2. User click del button in .
3. Dialog box got open.
4. We see if any checkbox is checked.
5. Then if any check box is checked we fetch id for taht user from attribute.
6. Call del() to delete that user.

here is code for dialog box open where checkbox need to be counted-

```
$(document).on("click", "#del", function () {
$(function () {
    $("#delete-user").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true

    });
    $("#none_selected").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true

    });
});
var checked =countchecked();
if(checked !="0")
{
$("#delete-user").dialog("open");
uid = $(this).attr("uid");
}
else
{
$("#none_selected").dialog("open");
uid = $(this).attr("uid");
}

 });
```

Comment: where is your code to add dynamic checkbox? where is html code? post your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: your code should count only checked checkboxes.

Comment: where do you call `countchecked()`? also you didn't post the code that adds the checkboxes you just posted the markup

Comment: i have posted countchecked() code also , check it  & help me

Comment: the dialogs initialization should go outside the click handler

Comment: but even that wont make count dynamic check box.

Comment: and what do you mean by "dynamic" exactly? you haven't showed any code that adds content to the page

Comment: koala_dev the content comes from plugin, but if there is any way to find dynamic generated dom elements , tell me how to use it on a function?

Comment: and how does the plugin work? are the checkboxes you're trying to access stll in the DOM or are they somehow getting replaced because otherwise your code shouldn't have any problems finding them (provided they have the right class)

Comment: When i view source they all are there. But when when i inspect table only dynamic one are here. Since i cant access them using normal jquery , they aren't in DOM. I suppose i m right?

Comment: yes, view source is not updated with javascript code, if you can't find them with the inspection tools then they have been removed from the DOM and you won't be able to access them anymore

Comment: @s.d remove auto load function, to call dialog plugin.

Comment: dialog is called only when we click on #del, so it doesn't auto load. Please elaborate? I am not able to find such problem's solution on google anywhere

Answer (score 0):

To count only checked box could simplify by .filter function

```
$('tbody[role="alert"] input:checkbox').filter(':checked').length
```

then to loop checked item

```
$('tbody[role="alert"] input:checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function(){
  //.. $(this) is the checkbox
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For dynamically added controls you will have to delegate the events handler function to the controls.

It can be achieved using `.on()` in jquery

Have a look: http://api.jquery.com/on/

For eg:

```
$( '#wrapper' ).on( 'click', 'a', function () { ... });
```

where `wrapper` is your static element and `a` is your dynamic element

like : 
    `<table id="wrapper"></table>`

Comment: The OP is binding the click event to a static element but having issues finding other dynamic content, `on()` is not the solution here

Comment: yes but `a` in my case is the dynamic element which is added to the static element. In case of him its the static table.

Comment: again, that will not solve the issue since the click handler executes properly but is the selector inside `countchecked()` that's not finding the elements and selectors don't need any form of delegation, plus we have now realized that the issue lies in the fact that the elements are being removed from the DOM, so they are no longer accesible

Comment: This solution is not what i am looking for. Since i need to call a function to count inside another function.